# AJAX chat window with scroll bar stays at same position unless the user manually scrolls it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my JavaScript code

```
var b = document.getElementById('chat');
b.scrollTop =b.scrollHeight;
```

but it does not work. I update the chat `div` dynamicaly using AJAX, but the scroll bar stays at the same position even when new messages are added.

How can the position be automatically updated to show the newest messages?

My AJAX code is:

```
function  ajax(){
     var id=document.getElementById("chat");
     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

     req.onreadystatechange =function(){
         if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
         {
              var res = req.responseText;
             id.innerHTML=res;
         }                  
      }
     req.open('POST','msg.php',true);
     req.send();
 }
setInterval(function(){ajax()},4000);
```

What may be my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You had better run script after data showed. You try this code

```
function  ajax(){
     var id=document.getElementById("chat");
     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var oldscrollHeight = jQuery("#chat")[0].scrollHeight - 20;
     req.onreadystatechange =function(){
         if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
         {
              var res = req.responseText;
             id.innerHTML=res;
             var newscrollHeight = jQuery("#chat")[0].scrollHeight - 20; //Scroll height after the request
                        if (newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight) {
                            jQuery("#chat").animate({scrollTop: newscrollHeight}, '1000'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
                        }

         }                  
      }
     req.open('POST','msg.php',true);
     req.send();
 }
setInterval(function(){ajax()},4000);
```

Comment: I used this code but srcroll bar stop in middle of div

Comment: This code use scroll div (#chat) to top of body, could you send me css code

Comment: #chat{
    
    
     width: 500px;
height: 450px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
  
    
}

Comment: I want to keep my scroll bar bottom of chat div unless user scroll it top when msg is add in chat div

Comment: You can add effect animate like this jQuery("#chat").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery("#chat").prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);

Comment: I used this query but scroll bar stay in middle of chat div not goes to bottom of chat div

Comment: sorry sir i got answer of my problem by using your query        thanks...

Comment: No problem, my friend

Comment: @Umeshpatil is your code is run well? i update my code. i have done with "chat" task in my job. and here is my code. it work for me. if your code is not run yet, you let try my code

Comment: You already have `id=document.getElementById('chat');` so why do you keep having jQuery search for it? `jQuery("#chat")[0].scrollHeight` is a big fat mess of a way to just get `id.scrollHeight`. And you can just do `jQuery(id).animate(...);` to pass it the element you already have rather than making it search *again*...